# Difference between `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` (wildcard) and specific origins

Tags: cors, same-site-cookies

I have a mostly public API with some parts of it "credentialed" behind cookies, similarly to e.g. how WordPress' REST API works. (In our case, it's a GraphQL API but that shouldn't matter.)

I want to enable CORS for it and am considering two options:

**Option 1**:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <dynamically return the incoming `Origin` header>
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

**Option 2**:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

(Plus other headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` in both cases.)

For what I know, both are secure – no matter what the CORS headers say, browser's cookie policy will apply and since we only use SameSite cookies, I think even if we serve this to `https://evil.com`, all should be OK:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://evil.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

There's no real problem – the evil site will be able to read the public parts of the API (which they can already do via `curl`, for example) but they won't be able to abuse a browser of a specific user that would be "logged in" to the API – cookies for our "site" will not be sent.

WordPress also uses Option 1 (for many years) and it's secure enough – see e.g. [this Trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45477).

Still, I wonder **why not use a wildcard** – it's simpler code (no need to dynamically read the `Origin` header), no need to worry about setting related headers properly (`Vary: Origin`) etc. The wildcard just seems simpler.

So my question is, why would I choose Option 1 for our API? What useful scenario does it unlock that wildcard prevents?

Comment: It looks like your are requiring credentials - or why you should use `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` then. But with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` you don't get credentials. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin): *"Attempting to use the wildcard with credentials will result in an error."*. Based on this this is not even a security question since your application simply will not work (i.e. functionality, not security).

Comment: Can you trust the subdomains or sibling domains of your site? Can you guarantee that they'll never have any XSS? If the answer is no, then option 1 is _not_ secure. The `SameSite` attribute does not give you a license to accept and reflect any origin in a credentialed CORS request!

Comment: @jub0bs I hear you but if WordPress can afford it (and it is one of the most attacked software on the planet and quite a strong focus on security, despite popular belief ) I think it should be fine for most APIs. But I hear you. Quite logical, IMO, would be if browsers went a step further and added "same-origin cookies".

Comment: Having read that Trac ticket: if that's what the people responsible for security at WP believe, its reputation for garbage security is 100% deserved. I'm not sure which is greater - the number of factually incorrect claims about how it works, or the number of instances of bad reasoning about what you should do - but that ticket is appalling. One notable sentence: "*CORS is built for CSRF protection* **[WRONG]** *, but WordPress already has a system for that (nonces), so we "disable" CORS* **[NOT WHAT'S HAPPENING]** *as it gets in the way of alternative authentication schemes*"**[WRONG]**

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: That's broadly correct, but the claim "you don't get credentials" is only true *for pre-flighted requests*. For "simple" requests that get made `withCredentials=true`, the client doesn't even see the ACAO (or ACAC) headers until it has already *sent* the credentials, and the server could choose to ignore them in that situation but in practice it usually accepts them. With that said, if the client sent a credentialed request and sees ACAO: * in the response, it will refuse to let the script read the response body (as if ACAC: false, regardless of any actual value of ACAC).

Comment: @CBHacking Good point. I should probably update my answer to analyse that WP ticket and mention the subtlety about preflighted requests (although the OP's requests most likely have JSON responses and are preflighted). I'll get to it later today.

Comment: The ticket is about an API server, which I believe requires explicit authentication (no implicit authentication, such as cookies or HTTP auth, which are what ACAC:true allows and ACAO:* bars), so in that case it's technically correct that option 1 is secure (though option 2 would work *fine* and be just as secure). It's atrocious reasoning that could easily lead somebody to assume option 1 - which turns off much of the same-origin policy for your site, to potentially catastrophic result - is safe for other kinds of sites, though.

Comment: As for preflighted requests, it doesn't matter what the response content type is (though the *request* content type matters), and also many web services that nominally only accept JSON will happily take requests using content-type: text/plain or x-www-form-urlencoded, so long as the request body parses as valid JSON, and those content types will not trigger a preflight (though other aspects of the request still might do so)

Answer (score 5):

## TL;DR

Option 2 simply doesn't work, and option 1 is insecure.

Simply hardcode the origin that you trust in the CORS response header.

## More details

### Option 2

As Stephen Ullrich pointed out in [his comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/251471/difference-between-access-control-allow-origin-wildcard-and-specific-orig#comment516737_251471), **Option 2 simply doesn't work** because the [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol) (which defines how CORS works) instructs browsers to reject this combination of headers. See [this relevant passage of the MDN Web Docs about CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards):

> When responding to a credentialed request, the server must specify an origin in the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, instead of specifying the "`*`" wildcard.

### Option 1

As for Option 1, it was very insecure before major browsers changed the `SameSite` default value to `Lax` (and many browsers still haven't made that change). But even if the session-identifying cookie is set with `SameSite=Lax` or `SameSite=Strict` and all yours users have modern browsers, Option 1 remains quite insecure. You write

> There's no real problem – the evil site [...] won't be able to abuse a browser of a specific user that would be "logged in" to the API – cookies for our "site" will not be sent.

Do not misconstrue the `SameSite` attribute as a license to blindly accept any origin from a credentialed CORS request! The problem is that `SameSite` only applies to *cross-site* requests, not to all *cross-origin* requests. To convince yourself that this subtlety matters, see

- https://web.dev/same-site-same-origin/, and
- https://jub0bs.com/posts/2021-01-29-great-samesite-confusion/

Can you guarantee that the subdomains (or sibling domains) of the origin that sets the session-identifying cookie will never have any XSS or HTML-injection vulnerability, or that they won't ever be [taken over by some malicious actor](https://labs.detectify.com/2014/10/21/hostile-subdomain-takeover-using-herokugithubdesk-more/)? If the answer is "no" (and it most likely is "no"), **I would strongly advise against Option 1**.

Comment: Thanks, we went with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` for our API in the end. It allows browser-based tools like Apollo Studio or GraphiQL to work for most of the API and it's not really a problem that they cannot send credentialed requests – for that, we have other ways to test the API.

Answer (score -1):

Using the Option 1, it will be more secure as you are "whitelisting" the "trusted origin sites" that will be using your API.

As for Option 2, it will be allowing any URL to call your API.